# How can I calculate the exponential integral?

Tags: floating-point, approximation, special-functions

(I [originally asked this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/116610/81372) in a different exchange.)

I'm writing a program that uses the [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).  Right now, I'm using `x/log(x)`, but I want to switch to something more accurate.  A better approximation is the [logarithmic integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) (actually, its Eulerian variant), which can be computed from the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).  Now how can I compute the exponential integral?  I'm on a macOS Intel system using Swift, so I can use the various advanced floating-point functions provided by Apple's system libraries if needed to help.

I did see [a similar question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/25105/4988), but I use a different domain (2 and above).

Of course, answers that involve a function better than `Li(x)` are acceptable too, as long as I can implement them easily.

Comment: For the exponential/logarithmic integral, I tend to use the series by Ramanujan (formula 15 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html)) for small to medium-sized arguments, and the [asymptotic series](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12) for large arguments.

Answer (score 3):

As with most questions about the computation of special functions, the [Digital Librarary of Mathematical Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/) is a good place to start.  In particular, see [chapter 6](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6), which deals with the exponential integral and $\mbox{li}(x)$.

You'll find that different methods (e.g. the power series for small $x$ versus asymptotic expansion for large $x$) work best in different ranges.

I see that Swift has standard elementary functions, Bessel functions, and the Gamma function but it doesn't appear to have li or Ei. if I knew of a special functions library for Swift then I'd recommend that you use it rather than writing your own routine.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need up to double precision, there's a c implementation in cephes that you should be able to adapt fairly easily : https://github.com/jeremybarnes/cephes/blob/60f27df395b8322c2da22c83751a2366b82d50d1/misc/expn.c